# Is there a way to see files inside directories by reading the parent dir using fs?

Tags: node.js, path, fs

So using fs, I'd like to read EVERYTHING inside a certain directory (let's call it parent) including other dirs, files inside the other dirs, and files inside parent.
For example:
Parent's path:

```
/Parent/
```

Everything inside Parent

```
/Parent/index.js
/Parent/utils/utils.js
/Parent/Structures/thing.js
```

How would I get all that? I've tried `fs.readdir` and `fs.readdirSync` but it only read the files, not directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have access to Bash in your environment, you could execute `find` using `exec()`.

Example:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("find /Parent/", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Update after comments:

Using a recursive function to get all files under a directory recursively:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const getAllFiles = function(dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || []

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles)
    } else {
      arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(__dirname, dirPath, "/", file))
    }
  })

  return arrayOfFiles
}
```

reference: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-using-node-js

Comment: Yes but I'd like to use fs.

Comment: How about using a recursive function for that? There's a method mentioned in this article: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-using-node-js

Comment: @user14428154 Updated the answer.